# Frequency Sweep

Tags: measurement, testing, frequency-measurement

I have heard the term "Frequency sweep" in testing context.

I want to understand, when we say frequency sweep, we give a start frequency and a stop frequency.

Assume a function generator with a Start Frequency = 10kHz, Stop frequency = 1MHz.

I want to understand how long will each frequency be given to our DUT by the generator.

Like, It will start with 10kHz, 11kHz, 12kHz and so on till 1MHz right?

I want to understand how long will each frequency be given to our DUT?

Like, for 1 sec you will get the signal at each freq or how ?

Comment: On a linear sweep each frequency is present for an infinite short time.

Comment: In a discrete frequency sweep you can specify a step size and a dwell time, being the time spend on each frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see what a 'sweep' is going to do, you need to read the fine print of the instruction manual that came with the generator.

It could be a linear sweep, or a log sweep, but will probably be linear if not otherwise specified.

It might be a continuous sweep, or it might hop from frequency to frequency, pausing at each frequency for an unspecified time, a specified time, or a settable time. It might be possible to specify what frequencies it pauses at, or you might just get ones it chooses, and it might not even be possible to tell what the frequencies are without measuring them.

If it hops, then how long will it take to settle to the new frequency after each hop? Only the most expensive generators are likely to specify that. Will the signal drop between hops? Probably not, but may do. Will the frequency make an excursion outside the range of last step and next step between hops? Probably not, but may do.